# Assign class fields with reflection BEFORE construction of the instance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, reflection

I want to either guarantee that fields used in the constructor are populated before construction, or somehow throw an exception if one of these fields is used in the constructor.

I am writing an injection framework for Unity3D. I have a use-case like this that emerged:

```
public class TestInjectable : IInjectable
{
     [Inject] TestDependency testDependency;

     int testValue;          

     public TestInjectable()
     {
          testValue = testDependency.value;
          //testValue is NULL here, because testDependency is injected AFTER construction
     }
}

public class TestDependency : IInjectable
{
     public int value = 5;
}
```

If I go like this, it works jus fine:

```
public class TestInjectable : IInjectable
{
     TestDependency testDependency;

     int testValue;          

     public TestInjectable(TestDependency testDependency)
     {
          testValue = testDependency.value;
          //testValue is 5 here, because testDependency is injected as a constructor parameter
     }
}

public class TestDependency : IInjectable
{
     public int value = 5;
}
```

I can use construction-parameter injection to make this work. However, after adding the [Inject] attribute for class fields, the idea of using those fields at construction, without constructor parameters, has entered the mix.

**First:** It would be nice to make the above work somehow... The created instance is required to set its field values, meaning construction must occur first regardless. I am not sure how to get around needing the constructor to run before injecting the fields.

**Second:** I would also be fine just throwing an exception for now, alerting the user that using an [Inject] field inside the constructor cannot occur... I was not able to find a solution for detecting if a field is used inside a constructor.

**Third:** If neither of these can be accomplished, I will have to rely on users reading the documentation, where I can explain this issue. Or, I will have to consider removing the [Inject] feature, which besides for this pit-fall, can be very useful for defining injection.... I would hate to take it out.

Comment: It's valid at the CLR level for a derived class to execute arbitrary code before invoking the base class constructor. But obviously that requires a fair bit of additional code to be generated to make that happen and may be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Your users should [prevent using dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) from inside the constructor. Object composition should be fast and reliable.

Comment: Your `[Inject]` attribute enables property and field injection, but that leads to [Temporal Coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/). Constructor injection is the preferred pattern because it *guarantees* a class's is constructed into a valid state (with all dependencies available).